# Cannot connect to 19c with SQL Developer though database is mounted and opened, error ORA-01034

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I have recently had a server crash that is hosting both an 11g and 19c databases.  Upon restart by IT staff, I discovered that one of the two 19c instances was idle. The 11g instances are all mounted, open and accepting SQL Developer connections.I was able to mount and open it using the init.ora file as an argument in the startup. I checked and the database is reporting, through SQL Plus, that it is mounted and open.  The listener has been restarted successfully.  However, trying to connect to it through SQL Developer I get ORA-01034. Any advice on what the problem is would be appreciated.

Error: ORA-01034: Oracle not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
01034, 0000 "Oracle not available"

SQL Developer is local and I have not tried remote sql plus as I am remoting into the Win 2012 R2 host server to run the commands. There is one listener for the database. Stopped and restarted listener and reports STATUS UNKNOWN for both instances.

Have not done anything with the environment variables. I do not have admin rights to the server.

Comment: can you please post the complete error message

Comment: Is SQL Developer local to the DB or remote? Can remote sqlplus connect? Do you have >1 listeners? What DBs do they say are on?

Comment: Update  Q: Did you set/update the environment variables?

Answer (score -1):

You have to restart your DB instances while listener's are up and don't restart the listener after that. When DB's are started: try to connect to them locally (just with username/password) and locally through tnsnames (username/password@tnsname) If listeners are shown correct status and you are able to connect locally with tnsnames: make sure the sam tnsnames file is on your client and there is no firewall between DB and client.

Comment: No, the imstande will retry from time to time to Register at the listende. So even of the listener is Not Running at imstande Startup of the listener is restarted the imstance will be registered